# No certificate error on Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal

Tags: powershell, azure, service-principal

I have automated few steps utilizing ARM template for Java/Tomcat deployment  but I am not getting success in automated login via certificate.

I have created a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL for a fictitious domain “project.company.com”. After following this article to setup an Application in AD and a service principal with contributor role,
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/#provide-certificate-through-automated-powershell-script

I am getting error

*“Login-AzureRmAccount : No certificate was found in the certificate store with thumbprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”* for following.

Looks like I am missing something at Azure subscription level. These exact steps work fine for Azure CLI from a Linux box but they don’t work for Azure PowerShell from Windows box.

```
$cert = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList @("<my-path>/project.company.pfx", "<my-password>")

#$applicationId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#$tenantId="dddddddddddddddddddddd"
#$subscriptionId="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
#Login-AzureRmAccount -CertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint -ApplicationId $applicationId -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId

$azureAdApplication = Get-AzureRmADApplication -IdentifierUri "https://project.company.com"
$subscription = Get-AzureRmSubscription
Login-AzureRmAccount -CertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint -ApplicationId $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $subscription.TenantId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the Azure cmdlets to detect the correct certificate you need to install the public cert (the .cer file) into the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried that but not sure what I was doing wrong. Tried again with mmc and added certificate (.pfx) in Trusted Root Certificate but did not work. Again imported same certificate (.pfx) under Personal store and it worked.

Comment: How do we do this on an AppCenter build so that we can call custom build scripts that connect to Azure (blob store etc..)?

Answer (score 1):

While it will work to install a cert into the trusted root cert authorities, this is not advisable as it impacts what other applications on your machine will trust.  Instead, install the certficate in the LocalMachine\My store or the CurrentUser\My store.